# Angular 2 with ngrx: using selectors breaks change detection?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I'm currently building an Angular2 app using ngrx to manage state. Run into an odd problem where if I populate an observable using store.select([state]) everything seems to work fine, but if I use store.let([getState]) I can't seem to subscribe to the Observable from that point on.

I have a component:

```js
export class Component implements OnInit {

  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  currentCategory: Observable<Category> = null;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<State>
  ) {
    this.currentCategory = store.select(s => s.categories.selected);
    // this.currentCategory = store.let(storeRoot.getSelectedCategory);
    this.items = store.select(s => s.items);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.currentCategory.subscribe(cat => {
      this.Items = this.store.select(s => s.items.budgetItems)
        .map(items => items.filter(item => item.category === cat.name ));
    });
```

The idea is to filter the list of items by category name when the category name changes. This works fine when I get state directly with the store.select statements, but when I try to use selectors in the store, the Observable seems to be assigned once and any changes to it no longer trigger the subscribe block.

```js
export interface AppState {
    items: fromBudgetItem.State;
    categories: fromCategory.State;
};

export const composeStore = compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)({
    items: fromBudgetItem.default,
    categories: fromCategory.default
});

// Categories selectors
export function getCategoriesState(state: Observable<AppState>) {
  return state.select(s => s.categories);
}

export const getSelectedCategory = compose(fromCategory.getSelectedCategory, getCategoriesState);
```

The 'compose' statement refers to a selector in the reducer:

```js
export interface State {
    selected: null
};

export function getSelectedCategory(state$: Observable<State>) {
    return state$.select(state => state.selected);
}
```

Any advice anyone can give? This seems to be the way they do it in the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app).

Comment: This is weird, I also faced the same issue. I forcefully invoked the change detection using changeDetectionRef.markForCheck and the changes reflected properly. Don't know why let is breaking the change detection though.